$\cos 2θ = 2\cos^2θ -1 = \cos^2θ + \sin^2θ$?
$$\cos 2θ = 2\cos^2θ - 1
= \cos^2θ + \cos^2θ - 1 = \cos^2θ + \sin^2θ = 1$$
I know it's not true. So, where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

Write $\cos^2\theta-1$ as $-\sin^2\theta$ and not as $\sin^2\theta$.

Your working suggests that
$$\cos^2 \theta-1=\sin^2 \theta$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\cos^2 \theta \color{red}- \sin^2 \theta = 1$$
It is not true, it should be
$$\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$$
